# when i used fast=fast->next->next at line 4 code run properly, but shows runtime error when i used it in place of line 8 .why it happend

Tags: c, runtime-error

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */


bool isPalindrome(struct ListNode* head){
   if(head== NULL || head->next==NULL) return true;
    
    struct ListNode *curr=head,*prev=NULL,*next=head,*fast=head;
    while(fast && fast->next){
        next=curr->next;
       // fast=fast->next->next;
        curr->next=prev;
        prev=curr;
        curr=next;
        fast=fast->next->next;
    }
    if(fast!=NULL && fast->next==NULL) curr=curr->next;
    
    while(prev && curr){
        if(prev->val!=curr->val) return false;
        prev=prev->next;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return true;
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman A MRE does not include the idea of "the full source code", almost the opposite.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the problem you observe and quote the full error message, verbatim, as text and directly here.

Answer (score 1):

You replace one of the checked pointers with `NULL` so that in line 8 this null pointer is dereferenced.

In the first run of the loop `curr` holds `head`, as `fast` does. But `prev` is `NULL`. Then `curr->next`, which is `head->next`, is set to `prev`, which is `NULL`. Three lines down `fast->next`, which is `head->next`, is dereferenced. Boom!

```c
    struct ListNode *curr=head,*prev=NULL,*next=head,*fast=head;
    while(fast && fast->next){
        next=curr->next;
       // fast=fast->next->next;
        curr->next=prev;            // head->next = NULL
        prev=curr;
        curr=next;
        fast=fast->next->next;      // ... = head->next->next
    }
```

Commonly you find such errors by debugging. Its an art worth to learn and practise.